# What do I need to install to develop Windows Phone app?

Tags: sdk, windows-phone

This might be a silly problem. My laptop has Windows 7. I have installed Visual Studio 2012. But there is no Windows Phone project. I have tried to install Windows Phone sdk 8 but it says that I need Windows 8 to install that.

I have tried to install Windows Phone sdk 7 but it says that I need Visual Studio 2010 service pack. I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install the Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 7, so if you want to develop on Windows 7, you'll have to install the [**Windows Phone 7 SDK**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570).

It includes Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. If you already have VS2010 installed, the [**SP1**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) is indeed required.